# How to resolve problem with Polish SSN Number?

Tags: python, series

I have a problem with the implementation of a new fuction in object type Series. I need to implement a new function which will be generating a random, unique polish SSN number. And I did it (I used Faker’s library and Pandas library)

```
def generate_unique_ssns(num):
  fake_unique_pesel = [fake.unique.ssn() for x in range (num)]
  output = pd.Series(fake_unique_pesel)

  return output

generate_unique_ssns(9)
```

It works. However I need to add code which will generate unique random numbers, especially for a sex and date of birth (polish SSN number has the form of YYMMDDZZZXQ, where YYMMDD is the date of birth (with century encoded in month field), ZZZ is the personal identification number, X denotes sex (even for females, odd for males) and Q is a parity number.

And this is my problem because I do not know what should I do right now. I tried to use "if / else" however I have only validated the generate number.

```
fake_pesel = fake.ssn()

def sex_ssns():
    if int(fake_pesel[9]) %2 == 0:
      print('female', fake_pesel)
    else:
      print('male', fake_pesel)

sex_ssns()
```

Comment: Many people have solved this problem. Check out this example (https://github.com/krzysztof-tatarata/random-pesel/blob/master/random_pesel/random_pesel.py) or this one (https://github.com/jsporna/pypesel/blob/develop/pesel/pesel.py) and try to learn from them

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

This code assumes that ZZZX can be in the range 0001-9999 and also that the check-digit is calculated using the Luhn algorithm (for which I've included a utility class).

The pseudo-random date will be some date between the date when the code is executed and 100 years prior to that.

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class luhn():
    __map = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

    @staticmethod
    def __sumdigits(v, p=0):
        sum_ = 0
        while v > 0:
            v, d = divmod(v, 10)
            sum_ += luhn.__map[d] if p else d
            p ^= 1
        return sum_

    @staticmethod
    def isvalid(v):
        return luhn.__sumdigits(v) % 10 == 0

    @staticmethod
    def checkdigit(v):
        return 10 - luhn.__sumdigits(v, 1) % 10


# generate a pseudo-random date within the range of current date and 100 years in the past
def rdate():
    return datetime.now() - timedelta(days=random.randint(0, 36525))


def pseudossn():
    yymmdd = datetime.strftime(rdate(), '%y%m%d')
    zzzx = f'{random.randint(1, 9999):04d}'
    cd = luhn.checkdigit(int(yymmdd+zzzx))
    return f'{yymmdd}{zzzx}{cd}'


print(pseudossn())
```